# Tornado ioloop + threading

Tags: python, http, tornado, web-frameworks

i have been working on tornado web framework from sometime, but still i didnt understood the ioloop functionality  clearly, especially how to use it in multithreading.
Is it possible to create separate instance of ioloop for multiple server ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vast majority of Tornado apps should have only one IOLoop, running in the main thread. You can run multiple HTTPServers (or other servers) on the same IOLoop.

It is possible to create multiple IOLoops and give each one its own thread, but this is rarely useful, because the GIL ensures that only one thread is running at a time. If you do use multiple IOLoops you must be careful to ensure that the different threads only communicate with each other through thread-safe methods (i.e. IOLoop.add_callback).

Comment: Thanks Ben, can u please give some more information on IOLoop class and its method. I am not able to clearly understand the use of instance(), current(), make_current() method of ioloop. Thank you.

Comment: In general, you should use current() to get the active IOLoop. instance() exists mainly for backwards compatibility (although it is sometimes useful when there are multiple IOLoops). It is rarely necessary to use make_current(); it's mainly for situations like tests that create and destroy many IOLoops.

Comment: Just curious, how to achieve "one IOLoop per thread" when `instance()`、`current()` don't create a new one if there is a IOLoop？

Comment: Create a new ioloop with IOLoop() when you start each thread and it will become current().